# Make jquery datepicker dates a different color every year on the same dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to make datepicker date cells a different color every year on the same dates.
If the month is 12(December) and the days are 18 to 31.
I do not want a specific date array that should be a different color.

I have tried this:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getUTCDate();
      var month = date.getUTCMonth();

      return [!( (day == 17 && month == 11) || (day == 18 && month == 11) || (day == 19 && month == 11) || (day == 20 && month == 11) || (day == 21 && month == 11) || (day == 22 && month == 11) || (day == 23 && month == 11) || (day == 24 && month == 11) || (day == 25 && month == 11) || (day == 26 && month == 11) || (day == 27 && month == 11) || (day == 28 && month == 11) || (day == 29 && month == 11) || (day == 30 && month == 11) )];
}
```

But this only disabled the cells. I do not want to have them disabled

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Refer http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VgekG/

Comment: But i have no dates like blueDates array. It needs to happen every year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change color for all 18 to 31 date of all year's December month using jQuery

Please check below code:

```js
$('#mydate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: colorize
});


function colorize(date) {
    if((date.getMonth() + 1)!=12) return [true, ""];
    if(date.getDate()<18) return [true, ""];
    
    return [true, "cool"];
}
```

```css
.cool a.ui-state-default {
    background-color: #03a9f4;
    background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<p>See December month of any year:</p>
<input type="text" id="mydate" placeholder="click here" />
```

Comment: That's it Thank you!